# unrelated tags to posts

Tags: discussion

I have rejected several attempts from @user4567570 and an already deleted account (javasystem -> lowercase) to add apex tags to unrelated posts, for example:
[image]

this is a lightning community, lightning component oriented question.

then again, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76320

for a soql and formula field related post. (looks like someone else approved ), imo it wasn't related.

and again -> https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76318
for another lightning component related post =(

and again (27-08) -> https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76642

and again (30-08) https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76859

and again x2 (04-09) https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/77092
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/77093

However, [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/46742/sayali-shinde) user seems to follow the same pattern of questions, answers and edits ("added apex tag") as the above mentioned users (further details in [this](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/possible-dup-account-with-similar-related-questions-patterns) post)

anyways, lately I have seen alot of these accounts adding a tags for quick rep

Comment: This user has been creating other sorts of problems as well, in addition to throwing the `apex` tag all over the place. The edited questions seemed to mostly be about the tag, but the last few in a row were completely irrelevant. I've temporarily banned this user from proposing further edits.

Comment: See a lot of tag edits with copied content or no usage guidance as well :p