# possible dup account with similar/related questions/patterns

Tags: discussion

user4567570

[Can we used same milestone(s) in a multiple entitlement processes [closed]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189200/can-we-used-same-milestones-in-a-multiple-entitlement-processes)

[Incompatible element type Time for collection of Datetime for BusinessHours](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189157/incompatible-element-type-time-for-collection-of-datetime-for-businesshours)

[Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [BusinessHours].diff(Id, Time, Time)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189159/method-does-not-exist-or-incorrect-signature-businesshours-diffid-time-tim)

deleted account: user46657

[Can we make the target response time configurable in an Entilement Process?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187245/can-we-make-the-target-response-time-configurable-in-an-entilement-process)

JavaSystem

[Calculate No of working days difference between two dates?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190028/calculate-no-of-working-days-difference-between-two-dates)

[How to add two working days using DateTime?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190033/how-to-add-two-working-days-using-datetime)

[Calculate the target response time using Business Days using Milestone](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190062/calculate-the-target-response-time-using-business-days-using-milestone)

Sayali Shinde - changed username from javasystem (all lower caps)
(can be seen in comment from adrian [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5239/date-calculation-in-apex/185411#185411))

[Calculation issue with Entitlement](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190068/calculation-issue-with-entitlement)

any thoughts? this user has a nasty habit of asking questions, not accepting valid answers, and then answering it himself - questions usually are/seem related to a particular subject.

doesn't seem to put a lot of effort into looking for documentation and seems to rely on the forum too much (imo)

Furthermore, their stackexchange profiles share interesting  subjects (as to the questions and tags) and I believe javasystems profile has recently been suspended:
[image]