# Best place to report duplicate user accounts

Tags: discussion

when we spot a possible duplicate user account, what is the best way to report it?

here in Meta? or by flagging the users questions by requesting moderator intervention?

Should we avoid calling them out in the comments?

For example [this](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/possible-dup-account-with-similar-related-questions-patterns)

Should we be posting posts similar to the above?